# Appearing of Inline keyboard after typing

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I trying to build survey telegrma bot. And list of the questions hade different types. The issue is that Inline keyboard where user must choose an option didn't appear after question where he typing. So I think it's an problem of some type of Callback.data but I cannot find the resolve. I will be very thanksfull for help.

```
`import logging


from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, Update
from telegram.ext import (
    CallbackQueryHandler,
    CommandHandler,
    ConversationHandler,
    MessageHandler,
    Updater,
    Filters,
)

logging.basicConfig(
    format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s", level=logging.INFO
)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5, Q6, AGE = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

user_data = {}

def start_handler(update: Update, context):
    keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton("Yes", callback_data=str(Q1)),
            InlineKeyboardButton("No", callback_data=str(Q1)),
        ]
    ]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    update.message.reply_text("Are you curently at water station", reply_markup=reply_markup)
    return Q1

def Q1_handler(update: Update, context):
    user_data[Q1] = update.callback_query
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()
    query.edit_message_text("Please write time when you been on water station")
    return Q2

def Q2_handler (update: Update, context):
    user_data[Q2] = update.message.text
    update.message.reply_text("Write time when you been on water station")
    return Q3

def Q3_handler (update: Update, context):
    keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton("5", callback_data=str(Q4)),
            InlineKeyboardButton("5-15", callback_data=str(Q4)),
            InlineKeyboardButton("15-30", callback_data=str(Q4)),
            InlineKeyboardButton(">30", callback_data=str(Q4)),
        ]
    ]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    update.message.reply_text("How many time you spend at water station", reply_markup=reply_markup)
    return Q4

def Q4_handler (update: Update, context):
    keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton("5", callback_data=str(Q5)),
            InlineKeyboardButton("5-15", callback_data=str(Q5)),
        ]
    ]
    user_data[Q4] = update.callback_query.data 
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    update.message.reply_text("How many time you spend at water station", reply_markup=reply_markup)
    return Q5

def Q5_handler (update: Update, context):
    keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton("Yes", callback_data=str(Q6)),
            InlineKeyboardButton("No", callback_data=str(Q6)),
        ]
    ]
    user_data[Q5] = update.callback_query.data 
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    update.message.reply_text("Are you satisfied by service", reply_markup=reply_markup)
    return Q6

def Q6_handler (update: Update, context):
    user_data[Q6] = update.message.text
    update.message.reply_text("Write time when you been on water station")
    return AGE

def finish_handler(update: Update, context):
    user_data[AGE] = update.message.text
    print(user_data)
    update.message.reply_text(f"Q1: {user_data[Q1]}, Q2: {user_data[Q2]}, Q3: {user_data[Q3]}, Q4: {user_data[Q4]}, Q5: {user_data[Q5]}, Q6: {user_data[Q6]}")
    return ConversationHandler.END

def cancel_handler(update: Update, context):
    print("bye")

def main():
    updater = Updater(
        token="TOKEN",
        use_context=True,
    )

    dp = updater.dispatcher

    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[
            CommandHandler("start", start_handler),
        ],
        states={
            Q1: [CallbackQueryHandler(Q1_handler)],
            Q2: [MessageHandler(Filters.all, Q2_handler)],
            Q3: [CallbackQueryHandler(Filters.all, Q3_handler)],
            Q4: [CallbackQueryHandler(Filters.all, Q4_handler)],
            Q5: [CallbackQueryHandler(Filters.all, Q5_handler)],
            Q6: [MessageHandler(Filters.all, Q6_handler)],
            AGE: [MessageHandler(Filters.all, finish_handler)]
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler("cancel", cancel_handler)],
    )

    dp.add_handler(conv_handler)

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

main()`
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, then just try to change how you set the inline keyboard:

```
keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=4)
                        five = InlineKeyboardButton('5', callback_data=str(Q4))
                        five_fifteen = InlineKeyboardButton('5-15', callback_data=str(Q4))
                        fifteen_thirty = InlineKeyboardButton('15-30', callback_data=str(Q4)
                        thirty = InlineKeyboardButton('>30', callback_data=str(Q4))
keyboard.add(five, five_fifteen, fifteen_thirty, thirty)
await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id ,"How many time you spend at water station", reply_markup=keyboard)
```